# How to fix procedure circular reference?

Tags: delphi, procedure, circular-reference

I'm new in the Delphi programming scene and i have trouble calling a procedure in a procedure in my console application.

My simple application is for a item inventory running through a telnet server on windows.
I'm using a old thinkpad as my thinclient running linux and a telnet client.

Using Delphi XE I've ran into a chicken or the egg situation.

I get addscreen undeclared indentifier... it is declared but under mainscreen !!!
If i put addscreen procedure over the mainscreen one, any call to mainscreen in the addscreen procedure make me an error undeclared indentifier mainscreen!

In simple terms, how to make the procedure to be call everywhere in the program?

I've tried interface and implementation but its not valid in a console application program!

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, windows, messages, Console in 'Console.pas';


procedure mainscreen;
var
  choice: string;
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln(' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
  writeln(' |                                     Inventory Management 0.1 ALPHA                                                         |');
  writeln(' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
  writeln('');
  writeln('');
  writeln('');
  writeln('');
  writeln('');
  writeln(' Make a choice: Add(a), Remove(r), Edit(e), Backup Database(bd), Mass Add(ma), Mass Remove(mr)');
  writeln('?:');
  readln(choice);

  if choice = 'a' then 
    addscreen
  else 
    mainscreen;
end;

procedure addscreen;
var
  choice: string;
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln(' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
  writeln(' |                                                     Add an Item                                                            |');
  writeln(' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
  writeln('');
  writeln('');
  writeln('');
  writeln(' Not yet ready!');
  writeln(' Press any key to return to the main menu...');
  readln(choice);

  mainscreen;
end;

begin
  mainscreen;
  textbackground(black);
  textcolor(lightgray);
  ExitProcess(0);
end.
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You would be better off moving the 'mainscreen' code into the 'main' program and moving more statements into the 'repeat' loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler passes through the file from top to bottom. At the point where it needs to deal with the call to `addscreen`, you have not yet declared `addscreen`.

Since you have a circular reference (`addscreen` calls `mainscreen` and vice versa) you need to break that with what is known as a forward reference. Add this line before `mainscreen`

```
procedure addscreen; forward;
```

So the organisation of the code should look like this:

```
procedure addscreen; forward;

procedure mainscreen;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure addscreen;
begin
  ...
end;
```

If you did not have a circular reference then you could simply reorder the procedures so that the `addscreen` was declared before `mainscreen`.

Comment: Thank you! After many unsuccessful searches of Google, i finally get the right answer on stackoverflow! thank you very much!

Comment: And the next time you search for this question, you'll find Google listing your question and David's answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: Circular reference may be not the best way to do it but it avoid the need of a loop in the main code. In fact main part is used only to call the first procedure then loop around in other procedure. Hard to read, spaghetti coding but it works! Thanks again !

Comment: I didn't know the `forward` directive. I think it also works without it. Since when has this been there?

Comment: @Smasher If A calls B and B calls A then you need forward directive. Perhaps you are thinking about methods of classes where the class declaration provides a forward declaration. The `forward` keyword has been present in Pascal since it was invented by Wirth.

Comment: argh, you are right of course. I thought of class declarations. Does it work in this case also? It would indeed be more readable.

Comment: @Smasher Not sure about adding `forward` to a class declaration. I'd guess that was a syntax error, but that's just a wild guess. It's never needed though which is why I guess that way.

Comment: @Smasher, @David Heffernan: you don't need the `forward` keyword regarding class declarations. Forward class declarations are on the form `type  className = class;`. See more on DocWiki, [Delphi Language Reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects)

Comment: @Fabricio Forward class declarations are a rather different topic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you mean `forward` in a *method* declaration?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: if so, `forward` inside a class declarations it's a syntax error...